# Assigning NULL to deferenced pointer of type double in gcc generates error

Tags: c, pointers, gcc

We are in the process of compiling a set of Pro C files, pre-processing and creating a set of corresponding object files.

When compiling one of the pro C files, we are encountering the following problem:

A pointer variable of type double is declared, say `i_ib`, as follows:

```
double *i_ib;
```

Then subsequently, it's dereferenced and value NULL is assigned to dereferenced pointer, as below:

```
*i_ib=NULL;
```

Above statement generates error in latest `gcc` compiler (version:4.1.2).  In the previous compiler, this statement was not producing error.  Please help us to get equivalent of `NULL` for double.  Your help would be highly appreciated.
Many thanks in advance :-)
- Murali

Answer (score 5):

To set the pointer to `NULL`, remove the asterisk:

```
i_ib = NULL;
```

Right now you are trying to assign `NULL` to the `double`, not to the pointer.

Answer (score 2):

@NPE [is right](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20287403/593047) about the correct way to assign the pointer a new referent.  But I wanted to add that if you need to preserve the code's behavior under the previous compiler version (though it's likely a bug), then you'll want to do this:

```
*i_ib = 0.0;
```

That assigns a *value* of `0.0` to the memory location referred to by `i_ib`, which is (probably) what your previous compiler had been doing.

Comment: @Damon, thanks, I've made it more explicit that this is not a good idea.

Comment: But FTR it's not necessarily a bug.  That depends on whether `i_ib` is assigned properly before it's dereferenced.  OP doesn't state that his two lines of code are contiguous, so it's possible that `i_ib` indeed points to a `double` by the time it's dereferenced and assigned.

Comment: I think that weird stuff in the original code comes from the fact that they use a pre-compiler which works for both C and C++. Probably someone habitually used to compile this into C++ where `NULL` is just `0`, not `(void*)0`. Zero converts fine to both `double` and `double*`, so no error is visible. But somehow, they got one wrong turn and assign a value instead of setting the pointer, and in C the conversion fails. You were 100% correct that the behavior of the original source is something completely different. I just wanted to point out that it 's UB and likely unintentional too. :)

Comment: Or worded differently, they probably have to check the original Pro-C code because something more serious is wrong in there.

Answer (score 2):

Well, a double is a double, and a pointer is a pointer. If you don't want that pointer to point to a particular double anymore, then either assign it the address of another double or assign NULL *to the pointer*, not the value it is pointing to:

```
i_ib = &another_dbl;
i_ib = NULL;
```

To change the double's value to *"NULL"*, you have to understand that a double can't really be null. A double is a specific chunk of memory, and you can't *"nullify"* that, unless you manage to somehow make that memory magically disappear.
The only thing you can do is set the bits in that block of memory to zero, by doing:

```
*i_ib = 0.0;
```

Whatever double `i_ib` references in this case, will then behave as though it's been *"initialized"* to zero
That's it